# drawing convex envelope of a function

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am writing an introductory chapter to my thesis report. I want to add a figure that illustrates the convex envelope of a function no matter what function, though, it has to be continuous. I'm not used to drawing with latex, so I can't see how to start.

the figure has to be something like this : ( but I am not asking you necessarily the exact replication) :

[image]

Regardless of the analytical expression of the function or it's envelope, can you help me pleas to do such figure. ( I prefer with Tikz )

Comment: Can you explain it in a beautiful way (hand-drawing or whatever)? What does it mean continuous and intutive thought?

Comment: @percusse sorry it was a typo. I want a figure of a continuous function and it's envelope a reader can simply and intuitively see that it's correct.

Comment: There is no unintuitive convex envelope and it is continuous anyhow. You are assuming this site knows about convex functions and intuitive looking envelopes. This is about TeX and please formulate your question rather asking for beauty. Then you'll get much better answers instead of commenting back and forth *Well that's not what I wanted, Oh then what did you want?* type of stuff.

Comment: I edited following your remarks @percusse but please edit if you think it's not enough.

Comment: Since you said: _I'm not used to drawing with latex, so I can't see how to start._ I have added an example as an answer.  This isn't exactly what you requested but I figure you can take it and modify it to make something like what you were asking for.  Then you can answer your own question and accept your own answer. :-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to do some reading of pgfmanual and its initial tutorials.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gray!30] (-2.5,0.5) -- (-1.5,-1) -- (-0.5,-2) -- (1,-2.5) -- (1.5,-1.5) -- (2.2,-2) --
(2.7,-1) -- (3.5,-1.8) -- (5,-1) -- (6.5,0) -- (7.5,1) -- cycle;
\draw (-2.5,0.5) -- (-1.5,-1) -- (-0.5,-2) -- (1,-2.5) -- (1.5,-1.5) -- (2.2,-2) --
(2.7,-1) -- (3.5,-1.8) -- (5,-1) -- (6.5,0) -- (7.5,1);
\draw (1,-2.5) -- (3.5,-1.8);
\node at (0.5,-1) {$f(x)$};
\node at (2.5,-3) {$g(x)$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, I will come back to vote up when I have the privilege to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find you get more help with TikZ questions if you include a minimal working example or "[MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe)."  Here's something to get you started.

[image: not what you were looking for but]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{pgflibraryarrows}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\TikZ}{Ti\textit{k}Z\xspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\resizebox{.97\columnwidth}{!}{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,name=#1}]
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-4,-2) grid (4,2);
\draw[thick,->] (-3,-2) -- (-3,1.7) node[midway,anchor=east,align=center] (y)  {Audience evaluated \\ {\scriptsize\textit{Quality of output}}};
\draw[thick,->] (-3,-2) -- (3.5,-2) node[midway,anchor=north,align=center] (x) {Time};

\draw[->] (-3,.5) -- (-2,-.5) -- (-1,-.25) -- (0,-.5) -- (1,0) -- (2,-.25) -- (3,.5) -- (3.5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\caption{You can learn how to draw with \TikZ}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will come back to vote up when I have the privilege.